# pandas ValueError boolean dtype in "if, else" statement

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, conditional-statements, mask

I'm trying to compare the values in a certain column ['Record Number'] of consecutive rows. I'll later (hopefully) be concatenating the strings in another column ['Desc'] into one row of the consecutive 'Record Number' rows, then deleting the duplicates.

Anyhow, the following "if" statement doesn't appear to like the boolean mask, since it throws the same error even if I use a.bool() like it wants:

"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
import pandas

with open('all.csv') as inc:
    indf = pandas.read_csv(inc, usecols=['Record Number', 'Service Date'], parse_dates=True)
    indf['Service Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(indf['Service Date'])
    indf.sort(['Service Date', 'Record Number'], inplace=True)
    indf['NUM'] = indf['Record Number'].shift(1)
    msk = indf['NUM'] == indf['Record Number']
    indf['MASK'] = msk
    print(indf)
    print(msk)
    for row in indf:
        if row['MASK'] == False:
        #if row['MASK'].bool() == False: ### this gives the same error
            print('Unique.')
        else:
            print('Dupe.')
```

How can I get around this?

EDIT: Fixed my typo (if <s>indf</s> row['MASK']), but now getting...

```
if row['MASK'] == False:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

and

```
if row[4] == False:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Why is it not allowing 'MASK'? And why is it crying about strings? 'MASK' is boolean.

```
Record Number             int64
Service Date     datetime64[ns]
NUM                     float64
MASK                       bool
```

Sample data:

```
Record Number,Service Date,Desc
746611,05/26/2014,jiber
361783,05/27/2014,manawyddan
231485,06/02/2014,montespan
254004,06/03/2014,peshawar
369750,06/09/2014,cochleate
757701,06/10/2014,verticity
586983,06/16/2014,psychotherapist
643669,06/17/2014,discreation
252213,06/23/2014,hemiacetal
863001,06/24/2014,jiber
563798,06/30/2014,manawyddan
229226,07/01/2014,montespan
772189,07/07/2014,peshawar
412939,07/08/2014,cochleate
230209,07/14/2014,verticity
723012,07/15/2014,psychotherapist
455138,07/21/2014,discreation
605876,07/22/2014,hemiacetal
565893,07/28/2014,jiber
760420,07/29/2014,manawyddan
667002,05/27/2014,montespan
676209,06/17/2014,peshawar
828060,06/24/2014,cochleate
582821,07/01/2014,verticity
275503,07/15/2014,psychotherapist
667002,05/26/2014,discreation
676209,06/02/2014,hemiacetal
828060,06/09/2014,jiber
667002,06/10/2014,manawyddan
676209,06/17/2014,montespan
828060,06/23/2014,peshawar
667002,06/24/2014,cochleate
676209,06/30/2014,verticity
828060,07/21/2014,psychotherapist
667002,07/28/2014,discreation
676209,05/27/2014,hemiacetal
828060,06/03/2014,jiber
667002,06/10/2014,manawyddan
676209,06/16/2014,montespan
828060,06/24/2014,peshawar
667002,07/01/2014,cochleate
676209,07/07/2014,verticity
828060,07/28/2014,psychotherapist
667002,07/29/2014,discreation
828060,06/09/2014,hemiacetal
667002,06/10/2014,jiber
676209,06/17/2014,manawyddan
828060,06/23/2014,montespan
667002,06/24/2014,peshawar
676209,06/30/2014,cochleate
828060,07/21/2014,verticity
828060,06/09/2014,psychotherapist
667002,06/10/2014,discreation
676209,06/17/2014,hemiacetal
828060,06/23/2014,jiber
667002,06/24/2014,manawyddan
676209,06/30/2014,montespan
```

Comment: If you post sample data from all.csv we can check the problem of typing.  But it the error looks like its due to comparing the series (index and value) to `False`.  Try `if indf['MASK'].values == False`.  We need to see sample data though to really see what's going on.

Comment: No joy, sadly. Added sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: the issue (aside from the typo discussed below) is how you iterate through a DataFrame. Iterating directly, iterates over the column names:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=list('abc'))

In [22]: for col in df: print col  # what you're doing
a
b
c
```

You want to iterate through the rows, so use iterrows:

```
In [23]: list(df.iterrows())  # tuples of (index, row)
Out[23]:
[(0, a    1
     b    2
     c    3
     Name: 0, dtype: int64),
 (1, a    4
     b    5
     c    6
     Name: 1, dtype: int64)]

In [24]: for i, row in df.iterrows(): print row['b']
2
5
```

---

It looks like this is a typo, in the sense that `indf['MASK']` (a Series) should read `row['MASK']` (a value). **You code should run fine on the value.**

*As noted in the exception message, the truthiness of a boolean Series is ambiguous (see some discussion on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/XzSHSLlTSZ8) and this was also the topic of several github issues).*

The basic problem is inconsistency with python and numpy (leading to surprises):

```
In [11]: bool([False])
Out[11]: True

In [12]: bool(np.array([False]))
Out[12]: False
```

and in numpy this raises dependant on the length of the array:

```
In [21]: bool(np.array([False, True]))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Rather than pick a side, pandas picks no side - keeping everyone unhappy, *but* with correct code.

Comment: Hmmm, seems confusing. But why is it treating the bool as str? if row[4].bool() == False:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bool'

Comment: row[4] *is* a string, it doesn't have an a bool() method.

Comment: Any ideas how I can compare column ['Record Number'] between consecutive rows? .shift(1) doesn't seem to work, either.

Comment: @user3478193 ooop, you were iterating through the DataFrame incorrectly, updated my answer. Not sure, you should ask that as a separate question...